# docker for toolkit documentation: `docker export` not including all layers?

Tags: r, docker, rstudio, rstudio-server, reproducible-research

After having given up on other means to document my `R` analysis environment(s) properely with the aim of analysis reproducibility, I'm setting out, to wrap each individual analysis into a `docker` container.
Here is what I do:

1. Pull the latest `rstudio` container from the [`rocker` project](https://www.rocker-project.org/):

   ```
   docker pull rocker/rstudio
   ```
2. Create a project-specific copy

   ```
   docker run -d -p 8787:8787 rocker/rstudio # Produces baseID
   docker commit --message="Snapshot of current rocker/rstudio container" <baseID> rstudio_project.2018
   docker stop <baseID>
   ```
3. Fire up the container:

   ```
   docker run -d -p 8787:8787 -e ROOT=TRUE rstudio_project.2018 # produces ID
   ```
4. `R`(`Studio`)- based project analysis ... finishing with `sudo apt-get clean` and `sudo rm -rf /tmp/*`
5. Export a docker image:

   ```
   docker export -o docker_rstudio_project.2018.tar <ID>
   xz docker_rstudio_project.2018.tar
   ```

After having deleted all related containers/images from my local registry, I try to emulate the revisit of the packaged project like so:

1. Import the container:

   ```
   docker import docker_rstudio_project.2018.tar.xz rstudio_project.2018.2
   ```
2. (Try to) Fire up container as was done for the original:

   docker run -d -p 8787:8787 -e ROOT=TRUE rstudio_project.2018.2

I am then faced with the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: No command specified.
```

What am I doing wrong? Where did the container loose (what) information on what to start by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `export` and `import` commands only handle the file system, not metadata like what command to run. Use `save` and `load` instead. See also https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1826

Comment: I see, but if I understand it correctly that will then require me to `docker save` all layers underlying a given container rather than being able to squash them into a single layer (what `docker export` does, if I understand correctly)?

So I cannot have the best of both worlds - squashed image + metadata?

Comment: @balin Yes, with `docker save` a multi-layer image stays multi-layer. But it is still just one archive file you have to deal with.

Comment: Ok. I have now converted my installations into a docker file ... building with `--squash` and then using `docker save`/`docker load` should get me away from the layer mess (if I understand correctly) ...